# My selection sort implementation returns a properly sorted yet reversed list, how do I solve this?

Tags: java, list, sorting, selection-sort

I'm making a generic selection sort implementation that receives an unsorted list of objects and returns the sorted list of elements (based on a comparator). Based on my UnitTests, it seems to do the sorting part fine except the list that is being returned is exactly a **reversed** version of the expected list.

I have already tried using the **.reverse()** method from the Collection framework, but that doesn't seem to work. Here is the code:

```
public List<E> selInsSort(List<E> items, Comparator<E> comparator) {
    // TODO implement selection or insertion sort
    //Selection sort O(N²)
    for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
        int min_idx = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < items.size(); j++)
            if (comparator.compare(items.get(j), items.get(min_idx)) == 1)
                min_idx = j;

        // Swap the found minimum element with the first
        // element
        if (comparator.compare(items.get(min_idx), items.get(i)) == 1) {
            E temp = items.get(min_idx);
            items.remove(min_idx);
            items.add(i, temp);
        }
    }
    return items;
}
```

Comment: I mean, you can change `1` to `-1`, though technically you should be checking if the result of `compare` is `> 0` or `< 0`.  `comparator.compare` is allowed to return, for example, `2`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#compare-T-T- - *a negative integer, zero, or **a positive integer** as the first argument is less than, equal to, or **greater than the second**.* - so, `comparator.compare(items.get(j), items.get(min_idx))` is going to be positive (and not necessarily 1) when the item at `min_idx` is *less* than the item at `j`. So you are finding the maximum element, not  the minimum one.

Comment: I changed the comparator from ==1 to > 0 and played around with it a but further but this doesn't seem to fix the issue of the returned list being in descending order.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there is no need to create selInSort() method but if you insist then you can solve it as so:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class CustomSort<E> {
    public List<E> selInsSort(List<E> items, Comparator<E> comparator) {
        // TODO implement selection or insertion sort
        //Selection sort O(N²)
        for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            // Find the minimum element in unsorted array
            int min_idx = i;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < items.size(); j++)
                if (comparator.compare(items.get(j), items.get(min_idx)) > 0)
                    min_idx = j;
            // Swap the found minimum element with the first
            // element
            if (comparator.compare(items.get(min_idx), items.get(i)) > 0) {
                E temp = items.get(min_idx);
                items.remove(min_idx);
                items.add(i, temp);
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

and finally you can call sort as so remember if you want to revese the list just change the comparator subtract from "o2 - o1" to "o1 - o2".

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Stackoverflow {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<>();
        integerList.add(24);
        integerList.add(10);
        integerList.add(3);
        integerList.add(55);
        integerList.add(65);
        integerList.add(0);
        integerList.add(10);
        CustomSort<Integer> customSortInteger = new CustomSort<>();
        Comparator<Integer> comparator = (o1, o2) -> o2 - o1;
        List<Integer> sortedList = customSortInteger.selInsSort(integerList, comparator);
        System.out.println(sortedList);
    }
}
```

and the result should be: [0, 3, 10, 10, 24, 55, 65]
what i am here trying to say is that you need to change your comparator condition to get different results.